# Autolayout working wrong

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm working on profile screen, there is a UITableView inside the ViewController and I placed all user info inside the UITableView Header. To make screen more accurate due to different sizes of "About" label I use Autolayout with this code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    sizeHeaderToFit()
}

func sizeHeaderToFit() {
    let headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView!

    headerView.setNeedsLayout()
    headerView.layoutIfNeeded()

    let height = headerView.systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    var frame = headerView.frame
    frame.size.height = height
    headerView.frame = frame

    tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
}
```

Everything works fine, but the last string of **About** label is not showing, text interrupts (I set word wrap):

[image]

Comment: Try increasing the textbox (or whatever the component is called) 's height.

Comment: @user202729 There is no height for the label, it's autolayout, I've mentioned in the post.

Comment: If you are using autolayout then you need constraints; setting the frame directly won't work

Comment: @Paulw11 I've also added constraints in Storyboard

Comment: add a height constraint on tableview header and try to change height constraint where you are changing frame. As you are using autolayout so you should play with the constraints rather than playing directly with frames

Comment: you can follow this tutorial https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasBhati thank you for your help! Please post that as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a height constraint on tableview header and try to change height constraint where you are changing frame. As you are using autolayout so you should play with the constraints rather than playing directly with the frames

> you can follow this tutorial

https://useyourloaf.com/blog/variable-height-table-view-header/

Hope it will help you.